# FBFriendPickerDelegate disappeared with Facebook v4

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I recently updated my iOS app using Facebook v3 to Facebook v4 (with Parse & Parse-UI iOS).

Problem is that FBFriendPicker seemed to disappear. Did someone find how to get such feature with the new SDK for iOS ?

Comment: hi did you check the answer bellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the Facebook SDK with the latest Facebook SDK 4.x and try the following code.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/appId"];

//optionally set previewImageURL

content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://exampleurl.jpg"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:nil];
```

For more detail please have a look into [App Invite Through Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview)

For generate app link please check [How To Generate App Link](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host)

Comment: Thanks :-) I couldn't check earlier because Parse SDK was officially bugged. Now that they updated their SDK, I could finally try your code!