# Using Facebook App Invites

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to use Facebook App Invites in my iOS app. I've tested this thing with test users (users that mentioned as testers and developers in "roles" tab) and it works fine. But there is one thing that I can't figure out: do I need to submit some items for review to Facebook before submitting my app with App Invite feature to the App Store? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522145/ios-facebook-friend-invite-not-working-in-facebook-sdk/30738908#30738908

Comment: @suthar, as I know Friend Invite and App Invite, that was introduces in FBSDK 4.0, are different things. Here is the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios But anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've figured this out only after submitting app to the App Store with this feature. All you need is user_friends permission.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your Facebook app has to be live and for it to be live you have to submit all the items the ask for review, in my tests they were privacy policy, itunes app IDs and screenshots, I set up all fake for my tests to get the app live and it all works, actually as per a bug report I opened to FB, they asked to add valid App Store IDs in the Developer iOS Settings (for testing purposes, it doesn't have to be yours, it just has to be a valid App Store ID) so I did the same with all the rest.